# Using child component in parent in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I have the following 3 level nested components in my Angular2 Application.
(layout/header/search)

```
layout/
├── header/
│     ├── search/
│     │     ├── search.component.ts
│     │     └── search.component.html
│     ├── header.component.ts
│     └── header.component.ts
├── layout.component.ts
├── layout.component.html
├── layout.component.css
└── layout.module.ts
```

I'm trying to call the search component inside my `header.component.html` but ending with a console error saying

```
'Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
'app-search' is not a known element:'
...
```

**layout.module.ts**

```
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { layoutRouting } from "./layout.routing";

import { LayoutComponent } from "./layout.component";
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';

@NgModule ({
    declarations: [
        LayoutComponent,
        HeaderComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        layoutRouting
    ]
})

export class LayoutModule {  }
```

**layout.component.html**

```
<div class="layout">
   <app-header></app-header>
</div>
```

**header.module.ts**

```
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";

import { HeaderComponent } from "./header.component";
import { SearchComponent } from './search/search.component';

@NgModule ({
    declarations: [
        HeaderComponent,
        SearchComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule
    ]
})

export class HeaderModule {  }
```

**header.component.html**

```
<header class="header">
   <app-search></app-search>
</header>
```

As you can see above, I have already imported the `SearchComponent` and and declared at `@NgModule`

If I import the `SearchComponent` in `layout.module.ts` (which is the parent component of both children), it works as expected without any errors.

I'm generating component using Angular CLI

e.g:  `ng g c layout/home/search`

What I'm doing wrong here? How can i use the search component in header without calling in layout? Please help me.

Comment: You need to declare `HeaderComponent` in your layout module

Comment: @Dummy It's already included. Please check my updated post.

Comment: Where do you use HeaderModule? And don't forget about exports within HeaderModule

Comment: @yurzui I use header module(<app-header></app-header>) in layout.component.html and search module in header.component.html

Comment: @Body that's the header **component**. Not the header **module**. Why do you have a separate header module. Where do you use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**header.module.ts**

```
@NgModule ({
    declarations: [
        HeaderComponent,
        SearchComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule
    ],
    exports: [HeaderComponent] // make it public
}) 
export class HeaderModule {  }
```

We export the HeaderComponent so other modules that import the HeaderModule can include it in their component templates. In your case LayoutComponent can include app-header in its template

**layout.module.ts**

```
@NgModule ({
    declarations: [
        LayoutComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        HeaderModule, // add here
        layoutRouting
    ]
})

export class LayoutModule {  }
```

See also

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#feature-modules